# How can I show product's price due to user's ip address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, rails-geocoder

I'm building an e-commerce site, and I want to show product's price due to user's IP address. For getting the IP I use this code: `current_user.current_sign_in_ip`. To get the region of the IP address, I use this: `Geocoder.search(current_user.current_sign_in_ip)`. My `Product` model is connected to a `Currency` model through a table `ProductCurrency`, where I store `product_id`, `currency_id` and 'price'.

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :variants
  has_many :product_currencies
  has_many :currencies, through: :product_currencies
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_currencies, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :variants, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
end

class Currency < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_currencies, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :products, through: :product_currencies
  has_many :currency_regions
  has_many :regions, through: :currency_regions
end

class ProductCurrency < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :currency
end
```

So, my `Product` can have several currencies (EUR, USD) and prices (100 EUR, 150 USD). For a `Currency` model, I have a joining table called `CurrencyRegion`, where I store `currency_id` and `region_id`. And a related model called `Region`

```
class Region < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :currency_regions
  has_many :currencies, through: :currency_regions
end

class CurrencyRegion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :currency
  belongs_to :region
end
```

So, what can I do to display product's price in USD if users IP address is from USA? Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code:

```
region = Geocoder.search(current_user.current_sign_in_ip)
price  = ProductCurrency.
           joins(currency: :regions).
           where('regions.name = ?', region).
           pluck('product_currencies.price').
           first
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems the solution I need